# EF Core with Pomelo Adapter returns error when executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am using EF Core 2.2.6. I have a stored procedure that I call using the code below:

```
var dateFromParam = new MySqlParameter("@DateFrom", dateFrom.ToShortDateString());
var dateToParam = new MySqlParameter("@DateTo", dateTo.ToShortDateString());

List<MyData> result = await context.Query<MyData>().AsNoTracking().FromSql("CALL MyStoredProcudure @p0, @p1",
    parameters: new [] { dateFromParam, dateToParam }).ToListAsync();
```

and I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@p0, @p1' at line 1",
```

How can I call it and pass the two parameters that I have?

Comment: Hi - I found this discussion. It might be of use? https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/194

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/953) about the same question for EF Core 3.0.

In short, use the parameter names exactly as you defined them and use MySQL's correct [call syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html) (parenthesis):

```cs
var dateFromParam = new MySqlParameter("@DateFrom", dateFrom.ToShortDateString());
var dateToParam = new MySqlParameter("@DateTo", dateTo.ToShortDateString());

List<MyData> result = await context
    .Query<MyData>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FromSql("CALL MyStoredProcudure(@DateFrom, @DateTo)",
             parameters: new [] { dateFromParam, dateToParam })
    .ToListAsync();
```